# Pass environment variable to provisioner in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I am using the Ansible (local) provisioner for my Vagrant setup. Is there a recommended way to pass an environment variable to the provisioner?

For example, I want to run `ENV=development vagrant up` and have Vagrant pass the environment variable `ENV` to Ansible.

I tried using `extra_vars`, taken from the [Vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#extra_vars):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |vagrant|
    # other configuration
    vagrant.vm.provision :ansible_local do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "ansible/server.yml"
        ansible.extra_vars = {
          env: ENV.fetch("ENV", "development")
        }
    end
end
```

However, when I run `vagrant provision` (without even using the `env` variable in Ansible), I get the following:

```
$ vagrant provision
 ==> default: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...
ERROR: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Removing `ansible.extra_vars` fixes this error, but then I can't accomplish what I wanted to.

Comment: That looks like it should work but I'm wondering if having an environment variable called `ENV` is clashing horribly with something in Ruby or somewhere else. What happens if you try `ENV.fetch("foobar", "development")` and then try it with `export foobar="notdevelopment"`?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The thing is, this results in the same error if I just do `env: "development"` – not really sure why.

Comment: Ah, there we go, it's going to be the `env` variable name clashing in Ansible. Try calling it something else

Comment: @ydaetskcoR That's not the issue. Changing it to something else stills gives the same error – the error coming from Vagrant seems to suggest something with the syntax, but I followed the same syntax as shown in the documentation.

Comment: It seems to be fixed in the latest versions of vagrant since I could do `ansible.extra_vars = { foo: "#{ENV.fetch('foo', 'bar')}"}` and then access to it in my playbook with `{{ foo }}`

Comment: An interesting link http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2015/11/12/vagrant-ansible-env-vars.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the plugin for Vagrant:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-env
```

I hope my code snippets will help:

```
config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |master|
    master.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
    master.env.enable # Enable vagrant-env(.env)
    master.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.10"
    master.vm.hostname = "k8s-master"
    master.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "./playbooks/master.yml"
        ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
        ansible.extra_vars = {
            env: development,
        }
    end
end
```

With config.env.enable added whenever you run a Vagrant command it’ll load .env into ENV which will allow your customizations.
And you can use this inside playbook as `{{ variable_name }}`
 .

Answer (score 4):

To access `development` environment variable, use: `ENV['development']` syntax.

You can also assign it to the variable at the beginning of the file:

```
development = ENV['development']
```

and use variable instead:

```
ansible.extra_vars = {
  env: development
}
```

Check the following [`Vagrantfile`](https://github.com/EA31337/EA-Tester/blob/master/Vagrantfile) as example.

Answer (score 1):

What is it that requires the environment variable be set?

I would try to use a different approach if possible. If you are expecting to act on the environment variable in ansible, you could instead set the value in an inventory group_vars file which would only be in effect for local provisioning vagrant. Other environments could use different values for the same variable by updating the appropriate inventory group_vars file.

Comment: Using an environment variable makes it simple for me to change which environment I will be using – of course, it's still possible using a file-based configuration, but most other production systems (such as using CI) will use environment variables for the same use case.

Comment: Agreed. As you say many technologies can be customized with environment variables. File-based configuration in ansible and env vars for the underlying technologies are not exclusive of one another. I could give a more concrete example if you are open to it.